# In vis.network, is it possible to set a node as the center of gravity?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-network

I am using vis.js to show a network diagram.
I need to maintain the "edge length" after dragging a node so I use the physics option.
My problem is that the node I drag always bounce back to its original position, which I think is because of these options.

```
physics: {
    forceAtlas2Based: {
          gravitationalConstant: -150,
          centralGravity: 0.005,
          springLength: 180,
          springConstant: 0.18,
    },
    maxVelocity: 146,
    solver: "forceAtlas2Based",
    timestep: 0.35,
    stabilization: {
            enabled: true,
            iterations: 1000,
            updateInterval: 25
    }
}
```

So what I'm thinking right now is if there is a way, where I can change the "center" to be the node dragged so that the physics center of gravity revolves around it?

Or

Is there a way to restabilize the network without having the dragged node bounce back to its initial position?

Comment: I think adding a minimal, complete, verifiable example (perhaps a stackblitz / repl) would be a nice way to illustrate the users what you're actually trying to do, and what is happening currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently no way to set selected node as center of gravity. But you could change their params like `mass` on some events like `dragStart` or `dragEnd`.

```js
network.on("dragStart", function(e){
    const id = network.getNode(e.nodes[0]).id
    nodes.update([ { id, mass: 5 } ])
})
```

Also to you can run `network.stopSimulation()` or `network.stabilize()` to stop physics simulation.

Comment: may I ask what would happen if I increase the mass? I'm new with vis.network. tia

Comment: @AceRivera as docs says: _By increasing the mass of a node, you increase it's repulsion_. You can play with drag events and for example disable physics when drag starts and increase mass and get them to default when drag ends.

If there were any other more elegant solutions i'd list them, but alas, this is the only thing you can play around with to get at least somewhat close where you want to be.

Comment: ah I get it now, I think this could really be helpful. let me try first before accepting. My problem is that my nodes takes long to stabilize and continues to move

Comment: @AceRivera you can actually run `network.stopSimulation()` or  `network.stabilize()` to stabilize the network (duh), maybe to remove mass and trigger stabilize on `dragEnd` for example.